# Is it possible to create an array of IloModel objects in C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, cplex

I've been unsuccessfully trying to create an array of IloModel object. Is there an easy way to do it ?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
IloModel* models = new(env) IloModel[S];
```

The code compiles but whenever I try to add constraints to each one of the models, the following error message is displayed:

Error:trying to add to an empty handle IloModel

I've removed the argumento from the new operator and added the following lines to code I'm wrinting:

```
    cout << "0" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i < S; S++)
        models[i] = IloModel(env);
```

But now the computer freezes when I run the code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong the line you showed, but the argument to `new` strikes me as odd.  You'll need to show the actual line that's giving you problems before anybody can help you.

Comment: I think every model createad has to be assigned to an environment. Do you think I should remove the argument ? This is the line causing the error: IloAdd(models[p], IloMaximize(env, fo - penalty1));

Comment: I don't know what framework you're using, but my guess is `env` needs to be passed to the constructor, not the `new` operator.  And please edit your question rather than putting code in the comments.

Comment: You're right ! env needs to be passed to the constructor. But I don't have any idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of *empty* model objects (i.e. objects without handle). After creating the array of empty models you have to initialize each of the models:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) models[i] = IloModel(env);
```

I am not sure about the placement-new syntax for allocating the array. Unless there is a very good reason not to use the default `operator new`, it is probably easier to read to just us that or even allocate the array on the stack.

*EDIT*: Here is a full code snippet that works for me:

```
   IloEnv env;
   int S = 5;
   IloModel *models = new IloModel[S];
   for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i)
      models[i] = IloModel(env);
```

Comment: I've tried that but It doesn't work. The computer freezes every time I run the code with that line.

Comment: Can you please adapt your question to show your full code?

Comment: Sure ! I've added the lines that are causing the error.

Comment: From your update it is not clear what exactly you changed when allocating the array. I have updated my answer with a full code snippet that works for me.